# How to get the version of the software when I use yum install command?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

Is there any way to know which version of the software will be installed using `yum install` command?

For example:

```
$ yum search zsh
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
=== Matched: zsh ===
zsh.x86_64 : A powerful interactive shell
```

In this case, how can I know the version of `zsh` if I type `yum install zsh.x86_64`?

Answer (score 7):

`yum list zsh` also works:

```
[ 16:27 root@host ~ ]# yum list zsh
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
zsh.i686                                                    4.3.10-6.fc13                                                    updates


[ 16:27 root@host ~ ]# yum info zsh
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
Name        : zsh
Arch        : i686
Version     : 4.3.10
Release     : 6.fc13
Size        : 2.1 M
Repo        : updates
Summary     : A powerful interactive shell
URL         : http://zsh.sunsite.dk/
License     : BSD
Description : The zsh shell is a command interpreter usable as an interactive login
            : shell and as a shell script command processor.  Zsh resembles the ksh
            : shell (the Korn shell), but includes many enhancements.  Zsh supports
            : command line editing, built-in spelling correction, programmable
            : command completion, shell functions (with autoloading), a history
            : mechanism, and more.

[ 16:27 root@host ~ ]# yum provides zsh
Loaded plugins: presto, refresh-packagekit
zsh-4.3.10-5.fc13.i686 : A powerful interactive shell
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:



zsh-4.3.10-6.fc13.i686 : A powerful interactive shell
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
```

### [man yum](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)

Answer (score 4):

Use yum info to get more info about a particular package:

```
yum info zsh
```

Answer (score -1):

```
yum -h   # to list yum options
yum info zsh    # lots of info
yum list zsh    # brief info (usually all I need: thanks @chown)
```

Comment: Why did you repeat the other answers over a year later?

Comment: Ok I summarized , explained the difference between list & info which is how I got here, and explained that you can get the list of what yum can do with -h.